# Create Generic Class C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

I'm working on a repository for a list of entities, and I should repeat thea same class more than once, the only difference is type type .. is there a way to make it generic?

It should quite easy, for sure I don't know how to make this generic:

```
 private Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository _rep = new Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository();
```

The class I'm repeating it this:

```
public class UserProfileRepository : IEntityRepository<IUserProfile>
{
   private Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository _rep = new Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository();

   public IUserProfile[] GetAll()
   {
     return _rep.GetAll();
   }

   public IUserProfile GetById(int id)
   {
     return _rep.GetById(id);
   }

   public IQueryable<IUserProfile> Query(Expression<Func<IUserProfile, bool>> filter)
   {
     return _rep.Query(filter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please look at this link for information on your question.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/entity-framework-generic-repository-pattern

Comment: You want to make Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository generic?  Then you could define a new class called Namespace.DAL.Repository<T>.  Creating generics is pretty easy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I just want to note that when you use these repositories that code that uses them should be using the interface IEntityRepository<T> instead of using your implementation of that interface directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NickBray hit the nail on the head. Regardless of how different or similar the actual concrete repository implementations are the `DAL` class in your example should expose the repository instance via an interface.

Ideally the exposed interface would be declared something like this.

```
interface IUserProfileRepository : IEntityRepository<IUserProfile>
{
}
```

This way you could add custom `IUserProfile` methods as necessary. While the `IEntityRepository` interface would define the common methods `Add`, `Update`, `Remove` and various `QueryXXX` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helpful for you. If I correctly understood your question, you want to make generizable your repository based on the interface "IEntityRepository".

Try something like this:

```
    public class UserProfileRepository<TUserProfile> : IEntityRepository<TUserProfile> where TUserProfile : IUserProfile
    {
       private Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository _rep = new Namespace.DAL.UserProfileRepository();

       public TUserProfile[] GetAll()
       {
         return _rep.GetAll();
       }

       public TUserProfile GetById(int id)
       {
         return _rep.GetById(id);
       }

       public IQueryable<TUserProfile> Query(Expression<Func<TUserProfile, bool>> filter)
       {
         return _rep.Query(filter);
       }
    }
```